# Protractor: Change style of a column header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

I'm here to ask you guys if there's anyway to change the property of a column header to be visible.

Here is the code I am using:

```
var column = element.all(by.repeater('col in vm.wijmoConfig.columns').row(2));
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].style = {};', column.getWebElement());
```

But the only thing I get is this error:

> column.getWebElement is not a function.

And if I don't use `.getWebElement()` I get this error :

> Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded

I'm so lost, please someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get a *single element* instead of an array, use the [`.first()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first):

```
var column = element.all(by.repeater('col in vm.wijmoConfig.columns').row(2)).first();
```

Or, use [`.get()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get):

```
var column = element.all(by.repeater('col in vm.wijmoConfig.columns')).get(2);
```

In both cases, `column` is an `ElementFinder` which has the [`.getWebElement()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.getWebElement) function.

Comment: Worked! Thank you :)